# Прошу помочь пониманием позиционированием элементов слоев и background

Tags: html, css, background, position

Делаю лендинг, в котором очень много слоев картинок, которые нужно позиционировать абсолютом и бэкграунд с кучей слоев.

Не совсем понимаю что правильно было бы вырезать как фон, а что оставлять и позиционировать абсолютом.

Больше всего вызывает вопросов нога, да и таблетосы.

Если не вырезать, а оставить все слои фоном, только добавить цены отдельно, то это вообще не выход.

Позиционируется очень плохо.

Возможно, подскажете, как верно разбирать такого рода макеты и позиционировать.

Верстаю на флексах и бутстрапе [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ссылку на макет покажите

Comment: Ссылку на макет дать не могу, но вышло как-то так. Вырезал ноги и таблы на отдельных 2 img, все остальное оставил бэкграундом. Позиционировал 2 картинки с помощью абсолюта и z-index, при этом на адаптиве ноги и таблы уходят под текст до 992 и затем текс спускается под весь этот сборник картинок. Итог адаптива, шапка, картинка с таблами и ногами по центру, после уже о комплексе, форма ну и остальной контент. Вот так на фулл скрин, адаптив еще шаманю. https://pastenow.ru/a3836f06ed2e747146ed59c6e65d1174

Comment: это плохо - на макете все запчасти по отдельности - а так даже зафотошопить не получится